# Is NEXTAUTH_SECRET variable the same as backend secret that is used to generate JWT token?

Tags: go, next.js, next-auth

I am writing my frontend app using NextJS, and using next auth for authentication (email, password login). My backend is a different code base written in GoLang, so when a user logs in, it will send a request to Golang backend endpoint, and gets back a JWT token, which is generated something like the following:

```
config := config.GetConfig()
atClaims := jwt.MapClaims{}
atClaims["authorized"] = true
atClaims["id"] = userId
atClaims["email"] = email
atClaims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24 * time.Duration(config.LoginExpire)).Unix()

token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, atClaims)
signedToken, err := token.SignedString([]byte(config.AppSecret))
```

My question here is related to `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` this envrionment variable I see from Next Auth documentations, as you can see when I generated the token in Go, I use this `config.AppSecret` (an env variable in backend), does `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` need to be the same value as `config.AppSecret` from backend, I am not sure what are the differences.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, No. The `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` in Next.js and `config.AppSecret` in your GoLang backend do not need to be the same; they serve different purposes in your application stack.

**NEXTAUTH_SECRET**: Used in Next.js for securing NextAuth tokens, crucial for session security within the NextAuth framework.

**Backend Secret (config.AppSecret)**: Used in GoLang backend to sign JWT tokens, ensuring the integrity and authenticity of tokens for backend.

If you want to use the token generated in backend in your NextJs application, you should do the following:

1. **Store the Token**: Store the token in a secure place on the client side. Common practices include using `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, or `cookies`. I'd prefer using Cookies for their ability to be automatically sent with each request and their security features like HttpOnly and SameSite attributes.
2. **Send Token in Subsequent Requests:** When making requests to your backend, include this token typically in the Authorization header. The standard way is to use the Bearer schema, like this: `Authorization: Bearer <your_token_here>`.
3. **Token Validation:** Your backend will validate this token on each protected route to authenticate the request. The token is decoded using the same secret key (config.AppSecret) that was used to sign it.

Other than this, you'd also need to handle token expiry, using https channel for transmission, and implementing CSRF protection if using cookies to store tokens.

But if you want to keep frontend and backend's authentication mechanisms separate and secure, you can use `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` in your Next.js application to safeguard NextAuth sessions and `config.AppSecret` for your GoLang backend to securely sign JWT tokens.